# How doesn't combining two eigenvectors that have the same eigenvalue for a specific matrix represent every vector left in the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a 2D plane and the hermitian matrix $L$ where:
$$L|\lambda_1\rangle=\lambda|\lambda_1\rangle$$
$$L|\lambda_2\rangle=\lambda|\lambda_2\rangle$$
Given that $|\lambda_1\rangle$ and $|\lambda_2\rangle$ are linearly independent, we can make any vector
$$|A\rangle=\alpha|\lambda_1\rangle +\beta|\lambda_2\rangle$$
that will be an eigenvector for $L$ with the same eigenvalue.
Can't I, with the last equation, create every vector in that plane and therefore every vector is an eigenvector for the matrix with the same eigenvalue?
I know this question might sound ridiculous and that there is a mistake in my reasoning but I can't find where is the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mistake. If you have a $2 \times 2$ matrix with one eigenvalue $\lambda$ and 2 linearly independent eigenvectors, then the whole plane is the eigenspace and the matrix is equal to $\lambda I$.

Comment: So if we are talking about an ordinary 2D plane the hermitian operator only stretches that plane without flipping or shearing it?

Comment: A hermitian operator can have two different eigenvalues, for example, $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ has two eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1$, $\lambda_2 = 2$. In this case not every vector is an eigenvector. If you only have one eigenvalue, this is a very special situation.

Comment: But isn't this special situation the one presented in my question? And in that situation doesn't the matrix stretches the plane evenly in every direction?

Comment: In your question you write $L\left|\lambda_1\right> = \lambda \left|\lambda_1\right>$, $L\left|\lambda_2\right> = \lambda \left|\lambda_2\right>$, and I read it as two linearly independent vectors with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Is that not correct? Should that have been $L\left|\lambda_1\right> = \lambda_1 \left|\lambda_1\right>$, $L\left|\lambda_2\right> = \lambda_2 \left|\lambda_2\right>$?

Comment: Yess that is correct. It not $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ it is only $\lambda$

Comment: If the eigenvalue is the same, then everything you write is correct. But not every Hermitian operator will have only one eigenvalue.